# XML Parse data within node

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse some XML. I have successfully taken the XML from the webpage using xmlTreeParse which is split into cards/meeting/race nodes. If i look at the 1st meeting node, how do i extract:

meeting name,

id,

diffusion_course_name

Currently whenever i try to extract anything, I only end up with the 'race' children. But i want the just the meeting details?

Many thanks!

```
> getNodeSet(top,"//cards/meeting[1]")
[[1]]
<meeting name="Bath" id="5" diffusion_course_name="BATH">
  <race id="680058" perform_race_id="" perform_race_id_atr="224436" details_available="1" race_status_code="O">
    <time>2:10</time>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <ampm>pm</ampm>
    <title>British Stallion Studs EBF Novice Stakes (Plus 10 Race)</title>
    <type>F</type>
    <distance>5f10y</distance>
    <group/>
    <tipsAllowed>1</tipsAllowed>
    <predictorAllowed>1</predictorAllowed>
    <bettingLink>1</bettingLink>
    <declaredRunners>5</declaredRunners>
    <liveCommentary>1</liveCommentary>
    <liveTab>1</liveTab>
    <raceDescription>Class 4 Novice</raceDescription>
    <tvText>ATR </tvText>
  </race>
  <race id="680061" perform_race_id="" perform_race_id_atr="224438" details_available="1" race_status_code="O">
    <time>2:40</time>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <ampm>pm</ampm>
    <title>Rainbow Casino Bristol Handicap (Bath Summer Sprint Series Qualifier)</title>
    <type>F</type>
    <distance>5f160y</distance>
    <group>Handicap</group>
    <tipsAllowed>1</tipsAllowed>
    <predictorAllowed>1</predictorAllowed>
    <bettingLink>1</bettingLink>
    <declaredRunners>13</declaredRunners>
    <liveCommentary>1</liveCommentary>
    <liveTab>1</liveTab>
    <raceDescription>Class 5 Handicap</raceDescription>
    <tvText>ATR </tvText>
  </race>
  <race id="680056" perform_race_id="" perform_race_id_atr="224439" details_available="1" race_status_code="O">
    <time>3:10</time>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <ampm>pm</ampm>
    <title>Rainbow Casino Birmingham Handicap</title>
    <type>F</type>
    <distance>5f160y</distance>
    <group>Handicap</group>
    <tipsAllowed>1</tipsAllowed>
    <predictorAllowed>1</predictorAllowed>
    <bettingLink>1</bettingLink>
    <declaredRunners>5</declaredRunners>
    <liveCommentary>1</liveCommentary>
    <liveTab>1</liveTab>
    <raceDescription>Class 4 Handicap</raceDescription>
    <tvText>ATR </tvText>
  </race>
  <race id="680055" perform_race_id="" perform_race_id_atr="224442" details_available="1" race_status_code="O">
    <time>3:40</time>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <ampm>pm</ampm>
    <title>Rainbow Casinos Cardiff Fillies' Handicap</title>
    <type>F</type>
    <distance>1m3f137y</distance>
    <group>Handicap</group>
    <tipsAllowed>1</tipsAllowed>
    <predictorAllowed>1</predictorAllowed>
    <bettingLink>1</bettingLink>
    <declaredRunners>6</declaredRunners>
    <liveCommentary>1</liveCommentary>
    <liveTab>1</liveTab>
    <raceDescription>Class 3 Handicap</raceDescription>
    <tvText>ATR </tvText>
  </race>
  <race id="680059" perform_race_id="" perform_race_id_atr="224443" details_available="1" race_status_code="O">
    <time>4:10</time>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <ampm>pm</ampm>
    <title>Rainbow Casino Aberdeen Handicap (Bath Summer Stayers' Series Qualifier)</title>
    <type>F</type>
    <distance>1m6f</distance>
    <group>Handicap</group>
    <tipsAllowed>1</tipsAllowed>
    <predictorAllowed>1</predictorAllowed>
    <bettingLink>1</bettingLink>
    <declaredRunners>8</declaredRunners>
    <liveCommentary>1</liveCommentary>
    <liveTab>1</liveTab>
    <raceDescription>Class 5 Handicap</raceDescription>
    <tvText>ATR </tvText>
  </race>
  <race id="680060" perform_race_id="" perform_race_id_atr="224447" details_available="1" race_status_code="O">
    <time>4:40</time>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <ampm>pm</ampm>
    <title>Rainbow Bristol Poker Handicap</title>
    <type>F</type>
    <distance>1m2f37y</distance>
    <group>Handicap</group>
    <tipsAllowed>1</tipsAllowed>
    <predictorAllowed>1</predictorAllowed>
    <bettingLink>1</bettingLink>
    <declaredRunners>8</declaredRunners>
    <liveCommentary>1</liveCommentary>
    <liveTab>1</liveTab>
    <raceDescription>Class 5 Handicap</raceDescription>
    <tvText>ATR </tvText>
  </race>
  <race id="680057" perform_race_id="" perform_race_id_atr="224446" details_available="1" race_status_code="O">
    <time>5:10</time>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <ampm>pm</ampm>
    <title>Rainbow Casinos Open 24/7 Handicap</title>
    <type>F</type>
    <distance>1m</distance>
    <group>Handicap</group>
    <tipsAllowed>1</tipsAllowed>
    <predictorAllowed>1</predictorAllowed>
    <bettingLink>1</bettingLink>
    <declaredRunners>8</declaredRunners>
    <liveCommentary>1</liveCommentary>
    <liveTab>1</liveTab>
    <raceDescription>Class 4 Handicap</raceDescription>
    <tvText>ATR </tvText>
  </race>
</meeting> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try xmls2js.It converts XML to javascript. Or you can use xml2json module of nodejs.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json

Comment: is that for use with R?

Comment: Sorry i should have made it clear in my question, that i'm performing this all in R, primarily using the R-XML package. Thanks.

Comment: Oops sorry, I mistaken